# Sack I has $7$ strawberry candies and $5$ chocolate candies. What is the probability that the candy taken from Sack I was a chocolate candy?

Tags: probability

Sack I has $7$ strawberry candies and $5$ chocolate candies. Sack II has $6$ strawberry candies and $4$ chocolate candies. Someone took out one candy from Sack I and one candy from Sack II. It is known that the candy taken out of Sack II was a strawberry candy. What is the probability that the candy taken from Sack I was a chocolate candy?

Since I thought the two events to be independent (The probability of taking an X-type candy from Sack II does not influence the probability of taking a Y-type candy from Sack I), I simply calculated the probability of taking a chocolate candy from Sack I as $$ \frac{5}{12} $$
However, some classmates claim that the answer is $0.25$, and their solution was unclear to me. How can this question be solved? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Based on that text it is impossible to infer whether the draws are independent. I.e. it's an incomplete problem. You can *assume*, however, they are independent, in which case your answer is correct.

Comment: If the candy from bag I is taken out randomly (every candy in bag I has the same probability to be taken out) then your answer is correct.